# Can't import all data in neo4j via batch importer

Tags: maven, neo4j

I'm trying to import in Neo4J nodes and relationships. I have 2 `.csv` files (tab separated) which look like this:

**users.csv** (it contains 10000 users)

```
userID   name
1   Cedric
2   Kirby
3   Zachary
4   Hoyt
5   Ella
6   Darrel
..........
..........
..........
```

**rels.csv** (it contains 100.000 relationships between the previous users)

```
idRel   id1 id2
1   4471    6462
2   4824    382
3   1936    9777
4   4448    5431
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16 and I'm using [jexp batch importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import).

Doing `./import-mvn.sh test.db sample/users.csv sample/rels.csv` I can import correctly all 10000 users but only 6077 relationships (not 100.000, why?).

I get this error in terminal: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project batch-import: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Node[100,used=false,rel=-1,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light,secondaryUnitId=-1] not in use -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should glance at the official import tool instead, see https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/

the format is essentially the same, except from header format differences.